# Inaccurate Hz detection of browser audio

Tags: audio, pitch-detection

```js
import PitchFinder from 'pitchfinder'

const detectPitch = PitchFinder.AMDF()
const notes = ['A', 'A#', 'B', 'C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'G#']

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      note: 'A',
      register: 4,
      cents: 0
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
      .then(stream => {
        const context = new AudioContext()
        const source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream)
        const processor = context.createScriptProcessor()

        source.connect(processor)
        processor.connect(context.destination)

        processor.onaudioprocess = e => {
          const hz = detectPitch(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0))
          if (hz) {
            console.log(hz)

            // ¢ or c = 1200 × log2 (f2 / f1), 1 semitone = 100 cents
            const semitones = 12 * (Math.log2((hz) / 440))
            const cents = semitones * 100

            // TODO: update component
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(e => {
        // TODO: handle error
      })
    }
  }
}
```

I have the above code in my Vue component (note, only some of the Vue-related code is attached for context.) I'm having an issue where the value printed to console is inaccurate. I used a drone and verified its pitch with other reputable tuners (A = 440 Hz). When printed to console with my code, the Hz is always ~404, other pitches are offset as well. Why is that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a sample rate wrong somewhere else in your code.

```
440 * 44100.0/48000.0 = 404.25
```

My guess is that you're running your audio input at 48 kHz but the pitch detector thinks the sample rate is 44.1 kHz.